# Workflow CICD gitlab for ios/android flutter app with fastlane and match

Tags: flutter, match, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

I'm trying to use the gitlab CICD for a flutter app on ios and android platforms.
I am using fastlane and match.
I don't want to use appcenter. Just to build and deploy to stores directly.

Can someone help me with the workflow in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and the two fastfiles? And maybe Xcode config if needed?

To build the android app I'm simply using `flutter build appbundle` in the gitlab-ci file (works in gitlab pipeline)

for the ios build I was told to use match. I've created a repository to store my certificates and profiles and ran the `fastlane match appstore`
I, at some point, build the ios archive with the flutter command `flutter build ios` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` but wasn't able to know where the archive was stocked and how to reach it. So i tried to follow a tutorial that was building the ios archive in the fasfile with the `build_ios_app` method.
but on the gitlab pipeline I have an err

> error: /Users/UserName/builds/XXX/ProjectName/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'ProjectName')

Currently following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/appditto/automate-your-flutter-workflow-using-gitlab-ci-cd-and-fastlane-5872e758165a).